# Platform target x64 but not able to leverage more than 3GB memory?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, com, 32bit-64bit

We are trying to leverage one 64 bit COM object, which is a black box legacy library.

It has been called in Windows application, runs at target platform x64, it ran successfully, while consuming 6-7GB memory without problem.

Then we try to hosted it as service, to call this COM object same way in WebAPI project, target x64, hosted by IIS Express x64/IIS, both throw StackOverflow Exception immediately at where COM object has been called. memory usage is close to 3GB according to profile.

This is tested on same Windows 10 machine, where this 64 bit COM object get registered. .Net Framework 4.7.2.

I assume this StackOverflow Exception is related to unable to leverage more memory.

Please help.

Comment: StackOverflow error isn't the same thing as OutOfMemory error.

Comment: I was treating StackOverflow error differently. 
Tried WinDbg but not able to capture exception stack when attach to w3wp process.  
Any idea how I can debug further on this?

Comment: Running as a service, you have a smaller desktop heap size and a limit on handles, etc. You can google for modifying desktop heap size when running as a service.

Comment: WinDbg should work fine to capture any exception but it's sometimes hard to get it right (I suggest you use the latest one 'WinDbg preview' which is nicer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-windbg-preview)